# Retirar capa ou alterar, blogger

Tags: html, css, background, blogger, background-image

Olá, estou tendo uma dificuldade com o blogger que estou fazendo pra faculdade, eu queria remover essa parte ver que esta escrito o nome do site, ou se possivel alterar para uma capa minha.

ela esta relacionada aqui:

```
#hen{background-color: #c82de5; background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c82de5, #67ad96); display: block; padding:100px 0px; position: relative; width: 100%;}
```

Comment: No display:block troque o block por none

Comment: agora saiu, perfeito, mas para add uma imagem seria como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As duas coisas são possíveis, deixar invisível ou alterar o background para uma imagem.

Para deixar invisível altere o valor da propriedade `display` do `CSS` para `none`.

```
#hen{
    background-color: #c82de5; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c82de5, #67ad96); 
    display: none; 
    padding: 100px 0px; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Para alterar o background para uma imagem seria o código abaixo trocando **URL DA IMAGEM**, pelo link da imagem:

```
#hen{
    background-color: #c82de5; 
    background-image: url("URL DA IMAGEM");
    display: block; 
    padding: 100px 0px; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Para deixar a imagem de background 100% ficaria assim:

```
#hen{
    background-color: #c82de5; 
    background-image: url("URL DA IMAGEM");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: block; 
    padding: 100px 0px; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito Pedro, muito obrigado.

Comment: Teria como deixar a imagem 100% ?

Comment: Fiz uma modificação na resposta para o que deseja. Basta usar a propriedade `background-size`.